# Javascript image slider sends text off screen and brings footer up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a javascript slider located on a page at: [crothersenvironmental.com/crothers/index.html](http://crothersenvironmental.com/crothers/index.html) that keeps sending the associated paragraph text under it off the side of the screen. You can see it under the slider down to the right. Once you click the associated numbers above the slider you'll see the text move to the right every time the numbers are clicked until they are moved off the screen and disappear. Also, once you click #1 the footer comes way up and then moves back down after you click any of the other numbers.

Any help, thoughts or direction would be very helpful. Thanks very much in advance.

Here is the js script I am using:

$('#recentprojects li a').click(function() {

```
var $this = $(this);

if ( !$this.parent('li').hasClass('selected') ) {

    var url = this.href,
        height = $('#recentworkimage img').css('height');

    $this
      .parents('ol')
      .find('li.selected')
        .removeClass('selected');

    $this.parent('li').addClass('selected');

    $('#recentworkimage')
      .css('height', height)
      .children('img')
        .fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $(this).attr('src', url).load(function() {
                $(this).fadeIn(1000);
            });

        $this.parents('#recentprojects')
          .find('p:last')
            .empty()
            .html('<p>' + $this.attr('title') + '</p>');
    });

}

return false;
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you do not need to empty the element before setting the new HTML string, as `.html()` already replaces the whole contents. The reason your subtitle is moving more and more to the right, is because you're adding `<p>` elements recursively.

Try the following:

```
$this.parents('#recentprojects')
    .find('p:last')
    .html($this.attr('title'));
```

Although in this case (as you ar looking up a unique ID) you could simplify like so:

```
$('#recentprojects')
    .find('p:last')
    .html($this.attr('title'));
```

Or if this is the only `<p>` you have within that element, you can reduce even further:

```
$('#recentprojects p')
    .html($this.attr('title'));
```

If you want to update the subtitle with JavaScript when the page loads, add the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var projects = $('#recentprojects');
    projects
        .find('p:last')
        .html(projects
            .find('a:first')
            .attr('title'));
});
```

Comment: Chucktator, thanks! That worked. The only issue now is that when you click back on #1 the text doesn't show up. Any idea why the footer juts up after the first circle is clicked?

Comment: That's because you don't have a `title` attribute specified for the first link. I've also updated my post with a few more tips that might help you.

Comment: aaahhh, right, title attribute. Thanks Chucktator, this works perfectly. Still having an issue with the footer moving when the first circle is clicked. I'll dig into it and see what I can figure out. Thank a lot for the help, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with this:

```
$this.parents('#recentprojects')
      .find('p:last')
        .empty()
        .html('<p>' + $this.attr('title') + '</p>');
```

You're adding the text into the last `p` tag causing a kind of recursive behavior.  Every time you add a new `p` tag, it then becomes the last `p`.

An alternate method for doing this may be:

```
$this.parents('#recentprojects')
      .find('p:last')
        .remove()
        .html('<p>' + $this.attr('title') + '</p>');
```

The remove method should remove the your old one and replace it with the new one.

Hope this helps

Edit -

Actually, you could just do `.find('p:last').html('yada yada yada');`